# Как изменить родительский контейнер выпадающего списка в select2?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, select2

Здравствуйте! Есть форма с селектами, где используется плагин select2. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: select2 просчитывает ширину селектов только при загрузке страницы (возможно утверждение ошибочно, но у меня так), поэтому для селектора `div.select2-container` задал стиль `width: 100% !important`.

Одну проблему решил, так появилась другая - поскольку `div.select2-container`находится в корне боди и имеет абсолютное позиционирование с отступом от левого края, его правый край выбирает из боди и расширяет его. Поэтому мне пришла в голову мысль указывать в select2 родителя для выпадающего списка. В документации плагина я такую возможность не нашел, существует ли она вообще, и если да, то как это сделать?

По [ссылке](http://cyprus.890m.com/Cyprus/agent_page.html) страница с [проблемной формой](http://prntscr.com/cxsln3), проблема наблюдается только в мобильной версии в режиме разработчика - при раскрытии селектов шапка [смещается вправо](http://prntscr.com/cxsln3).

UPD: добавил стандартный селект, где видно что выпадающий список располагается в корне body.

UPDD: нашел [здесь](https://select2.github.io/options-old.html#dropdown) вариант с использованием `AttachContainer`, попробовал, - выпадающий список остается на прежнем месте. Внес изменения в код.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
    AttachContainer: $('.wrapper')
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <select class="js-example-basic-single" style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: предоставьте код сюда.

Comment: добавил код обычного селекта

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для указания родительского элемента, для выпадающего списка нужно использовать свойство [dropdownParent](https://select2.github.io/options.html#dropdownParent)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
    dropdownParent: $('.wrapper')
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <select class="js-example-basic-single" style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

---

К вопросу в комментарии: так как сейчас выбираются *все* элементы с классом *wrapper*, может быть проблема если таких элементов несколько. Для решения, нужно выбирать элементы контейнеры относительно элемента селекта:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").each(function() { // бежим по всем селектам
    $(this).select2({ // ини циализируем каждый отдельно
      minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
      dropdownParent: $(this).closest('.wrapper') // выбираем конкретный элемент с классом, относительно текущего селекта
    })
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <select class="js-example-basic-single" style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <select class="js-example-basic-single" style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ, невнимательность с моей стороны. Просьба ответить еще на один вопрос: форма, которую вы видите на сайте, имеет расширенный аналог (с доп.полями) в виде модального окна. Т.е. ряд селектов повторяется. Проблема в том, что повторяющиеся селекты перестают корректно работать, т.е. приходится выполнять инициализацию повторно, но это, я полагаю, не самое оптимальное решение. Есть ли более рациональный вариант?  http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/pEYAxk

Comment: @Игорь, обновил ответ